# Объявление структуры в структуре

Tags: c++, классы

Подскажите пожалуйста, как все таки можно определить вот такую структуру ?

```
struct my_struct_1
{
    int my_int;
    void (*my_func_p) (my_result* my_struct_result_p);

};


struct my_struct_2
{
    char my_char;
};



struct my_result
{
    my_struct_1 my_struct_1_;
    my_struct_2 my_struct_2_;
};



int main()
{

}
```

Компилятор ругается на синтаксическую ошибку идентификатора my_result.

Я могу сделать так:

```
struct my_struct_1
{
    int my_int;
    //void (*my_func_p) (my_result* my_struct_result_p); - удаляю из этой структуры
};


struct my_struct_2
{
    char my_char;
};



struct my_result
{
    my_struct_1 my_struct_1_;
    my_struct_2 my_struct_2_;
    void (*my_func_p) (my_result* my_struct_result_p);
};
```

Но так менее удобно. Позволяет ли с++ сделать именно, как в первом примере ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте самой первой строчкой

```
struct my_result;
```

Comment: а подскажите, как это работает ? Не могу понять. :( То есть все заработало, но, что то не соображу почему.

Comment: Предварительное объявление ([forward declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class)). Теперь компилятор знает, что такое имя будет объявлено, а потому может работать с указателями и ссылками на него.